# Generate various events in 'Web scraping with beautiful soup'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to generate various events like:

- filling an input field
- submitting a form
- clicking a link
- Handling redirection etc

via python beautiful soup library. If not what's the best way to do above (basic functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is a tool for parsing and analyzing HTML. It cannot talk to web servers, so you'd need another library to do that, like `urllib2` (builtin, but low-level) or `requests` (high-level, handles cookies, redirection, https etc. out of the box). Alternatively, you can look at `mechanize` or `windmill`, or if you also require JavaScript code to be executed, `phantomjs`.